# AttributeError : has no attribute 'BatchNormalizationBase

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

when I run the script, there is error

```
File "akurasi.py", line 3, in <module>
import keras
    File "C:\projeku\Lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import tf2
    File "C:\projeku\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\projeku\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "C:\projeku\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import models
  File "C:\projeku\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\models.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import metrics as metrics_module
  File "C:\projeku\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
  File "C:\projeku\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\activations.py", line 18, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import advanced_activations
  File "C:\projeku\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\__init__.py", line 147, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization_v2 import SyncBatchNormalization
  File "C:\projeku\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\normalization_v2.py", line 29, in <module>
    class SyncBatchNormalization(normalization.BatchNormalizationBase):
AttributeError: *module 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization'* has no attribute **'BatchNormalizationBase'**
```

in my script there is no "import tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization". could somebody help me? how to solve this problem? thank you :)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D , MaxPool2D , Flatten , Dropout 
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import Adam

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix

import tensorflow as tf

import cv2
import os

import numpy as np
```

Comment: why do you need both keras and tensorflow? Cannot you use only tf.keras?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue can be resolved, once you modify imports as shown below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D , MaxPool2D , Flatten , Dropout 
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix
import cv2
import os

import numpy as np
```